# Use "window.onload" in phantomjs

Tags: node.js, phantomjs

I'm scraping data from AJAX-based pages using PhantomJS through the `npm-phantom` module. Sometimes the data isn't loaded yet when phantom starts DOM traversal. How to insert something like `window.onload = function() { ... }` into the `page.evaluate`? It returns me a function, but not the data.

```
var phantom = require('phantom');

exports.main = function (url, callback) {
    phantom.create(function (ph) {
        ph.createPage(function (page) {
            page.open(pref + url, function (status) {
                page.evaluate(function () {
                    // here  
                    var data = {};
                    data.one = document.getElementById("first").innerText;
                    data.two = document.getElementById("last").innerText;
                    return data;
                },
                function (res) {
                    callback(null, res);
                    ph.exit();
                });
            });
        });
    });
}
```

On the PhantomJS API page I found [onLoadFinished](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/handler/on-load-finished.html), but how does it apply.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`page.open(url, function(status){...})` is just another notation for

```
page.onLoadFinished = function(status){...};
page.open(url);
```

You can find the quote [here](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/handler/on-load-finished.html):

> Also see <kbd>[WebPage#open](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/method/open.html)</kbd> for an alternate hook for the <kbd>onLoadFinished</kbd> callback.

---

Since this is an AJAX-based page, you need to wait for the data to appear. You can only do that by repeatedly checking a specific portion of the page.

You can find an example in the *examples* directory of the phantomjs *installation* or [here](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/blob/master/examples/waitfor.js). This will probably also work for phantomjs through npm-phantom.

In your case this will look like this (abbreviated):

```
page.open(pref + url, function (status) {
   waitFor(function check(){
       return page.evaluate(function () {
           // ensure #first and #last are in the DOM
           return !!document.getElementById("first") && 
                  !!document.getElementById("last");
       });

   }, function onReady(){
       page.evaluate(function () {
           var data = {};
           data.one = document.getElementById("first").innerText;
           data.two = document.getElementById("last").innerText;
           return data;
        });
        callback(null, res);
        ph.exit();
   }, 5000); // some timeout
});
```