# NodeJS API for PhantomJS open method doesn't execute full javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, phantomjs

I'am trying to use Phantom (npm install phantom) with Node and it seems all javascript is not executed before Page.open returns promise fullfilled. Is there a way to make sure all javascript gets executed.

```
    var args = []; // ["--platform windows:dpiawareness=0"];
    phantom.create(args).then((ph) => {
        VAR.ph = ph;
        return ph.createPage();

    }).then((page) => {
        VAR.page = page;
        return page.setting( "resourceTimeout", STATIC.phantomResourceTimeout );

    }).then(() => {
        return VAR.page.open(url);
```

So, when promise returns from page.open it sometimes returns full page and sometimes page where script is partially executed.

```
    VAR.page.property('content');
```

And when  retrieve content from this it is not full page?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use "window.onload" in phantomjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24865467/use-window-onload-in-phantomjs)

Comment: PhantomJS has been **abandoned**, you could try GoogleChrome/puppeteer that uses **headless** Chromium. The library has many capabilities.

Answer (score -1):

Try using something like this:

```
page.onLoadFinished = function(status){
   // do whatever you want
};
```

I'm sure the error is just happening because your page hasn't finished loading yet. Use this code to run your functions after **the page load event** to avoid errors.

Greetings.